# call a function on load of a page called with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

i have the following problem:
I'm using a wordpress theme, that calls the page with ajax.

[This is the demo theme.](http://depth.dream-demo.com/)

I've created some custom page, with ajax and jquery code.
There is a function in

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($){

});
```

but with ajax page loaded doesn't works.
Could you help me please ?

Thanks and excuse me for my english.

Comment: Does the console show any errors?

Comment: @m59 ..is valid syntax, used to alias `$` within ready....http://api.jquery.com/ready/ ( see: Aliasing the jQuery Namespace)

Comment: The theme allow you to disable AJAX system. If i disable AJAX, and the page is called "normally" in wordpress , whitout AJAX call, it's works. If you take a look at demo, you can see that AJAX call the page in this way: current_url/#!/new_page_url.